# How to remove a date 1.1.0001 in DevExpress datetime

Tags: date, devexpress

When I get a null value for date, in my DevExpress control I always get a date with value 1.1.0001.

Comment: Which control? DateEdit? How to you set/get the value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`RepositoryItemDateEdit.NullDate`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemDateEdit_NullDatetopic) property. Set it to `DateTime.MinValue`, so you will never see the `1.1.0001` text in your `DateEdit`.
Here is example:

```cs
dateEdit1.Properties.NullDate = DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

test the value date before assigning the DevExpress controls, for example:

```
if (inputDate != DateTime.MinValue)
```